# Как установить значение checked для mat-selected (Angular Material)?

Tags: angular2, typescript, angular4, angular-material

По сути использую пример https://stackblitz.com/angular/qvpjxrjarkj

Шаблон компонента

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Columns" [formControl]="settings" multiple>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let key of tableData"
                [value]="key.name"
                (click)="toggle(key)"
    >{{key.name}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

tableData это массив объектов вида {name: string, visible : boolean}.
Как сделать так, что бы исходя из значения visible, чекбокс менял свое состояние.
Проблема в том что, библиотека создаёт хтмл элемент mat-pseudo-checkbox,который не знаю как изменить

Answer (score 0):

Используй  [(ngModel)]

пример:

```
<input type="checkbox"
         [(ngModel)]="key.visible"
         (change)="onCheckedChange()">
```